# text from input field into onmouseclick event

Tags: javascript

I want to track the terms from a search field on my website. The terms should be transferred to my tracking tool (etracker). etracker can get it via onmouseclick event.

Thats my current code:

```
<div class="form-group autocomplete">
<div class="input-group search">
<input id="search" name="searchterm" type="search" class="form-control form-control search-input" placeholder="Please enter a search term" autocomplete="off">
div class="input-group-btn">
<button type="submit" class="btn color-cta-3 search-button" onmousedown="ET_Event.eventStart('searchterm', 'search')">Search</button></div></div>
```

What I need is n JavaScript, which will copy the entered search term from the input field to the onmousedown event. Is it somehow possible? Maybe something like "searchterm.value = variablexy" + the variable inside the event code?

Comment: Data does not need to get copied into events. Events are moments in time. At those moments, you simply go and look where the data should be and get it. There is no copying. Also, with a button, you want the `click` event, not `mousedown` and with `submit` buttons, you want the `form` element's `submit` event, not the button's events at all.

Comment: In your JS, you will want to grab the input element `document.getElementById("search")` and pass its value `document.getElementById("search").value` to your thingy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button it gets the search criteria and then calls your `ET_Event.eventStart` function(if it is a js function) while passing the text from the input

```js
function getInput(){
ET_Event.eventStart(document.getElementById('search').value, 'search')
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group autocomplete">
<div class="input-group search">
<input id="search" name="searchterm" type="search" class="form-control form-control search-input" placeholder="Please enter a search term" autocomplete="off">
<div class="input-group-btn">
<button type="submit" class="btn color-cta-3 search-button" onmousedown="getInput(); return false;">Search</button></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Scath. Unfortunately, I cant try it, because my only possibility to add the script, is the way via script tag (I know, it's a bad way) and my CMS always delete that part after saving it.  Is there a possibility, to add the JavaScript in another way? Without separate script part?

Comment: I changed the answer and added a new button to test with, you can but the javascript right in the onmousedown event and then go get the inputs value and then pass it to your event from there I beleive

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the updated version does not work correctly. Could you send me the previous one again please? I will try to find a way, to add the script in a proper way. Thanks @scath

Comment: I put it back to the original.